# How to use UITextRange to get substring from a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

So I am using selectedTextRange to get a cursor position from my UITextField. I would like to obtain a substring from the beginning of my TextField text up to the cursor position. How would I go about doing this? I am able to create the UITextRange I want but I don't know how to use this to get the actual substring since substringWithRange seems to only work with NSRange. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the methods from the `UITextInput` protocol, which is implemented by all text views, to do this. With a text range, you can simply call `textInRange:` to get the text.

To get the text from the beginning of the field up to the selected position, you'll need to make a text range first with `textRangeFromPosition:toPosition:`, passing `beginningOfDocument` for the first argument, and the `start` of your text range for the second argument.